# Is there a silverlight repeater control (like in ASP.NET)?

Tags: silverlight

I need to show a list of many text strings, each on a line.

I need items to be selectable, so i cant use an ItemsControl.

I only need one "column" and no sorting, so a DataGrid might be too heavyweight (???)
I need up to 1000 items, so a Listbox might be too lightweight (???)

What Silverlight control (or Toolkit control) would be best for this use?

Answer (score 7):

The functional equivalent of  is indeed .
If you need an ItemsControl that has Selection, use one of the classes the inherit from Selector (which coincidently itself inherits from ItemsControl):
1. ComboBox
2. ListBox
3. TreeView (Selector API)
4.  AutoCompleteBox (Selector API)

All of these support the same ItemsControl API of ItemsControl.ItemTemplate=DataTemplate.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the selection mode for a ListBox?

Answer (score 3):

DataGrid has good performance because of virtualization:

> The DataGrid boasts excellent performance with large sets of data
>   because it uses virtualization, unlike any other Silverlight control. That means the
>   DataGrid only retains in-memory objects for the data that’s currently visible, not the
>   entire set of data that’s loaded. This reduces the memory overhead dramatically and
>   allows it to practically hold thousands (or even millions) of rows. The only tradeoff is
>   that the DataGrid is slightly slower when scrolling, because it needs to clear the current
>   set of DataGridRow objects and load the information that corresponds to the new rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the **HeaderedItemsControl** from the **Silverlight Toolkit**. Here's an article: [HEADEREDCONTENTCONTROL & HEADEREDITEMSCONTROL](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/11/silverlight-toolkit-headeredcontentcontrol-amp-headereditemscontrol.aspx)